# The location of the iframe is about:blank

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe

Here is the example code:

```
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com/js/"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
var xwin = window.frames[0];
console.log(xwin.location);
</script>
```

Even if the link "http://www.w3schools.com/js/" has been opened, the output log message is 'about:blank' instead of 'http://www.w3schools.com/js'.
What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

It will not work because of the "Same Origin" policy. You are not allowed to access variables in a frame pointing to another domain. There are a lot of articles on the Internet, just search for "javascript same origin policy". Here is an example: http://javascript.info/tutorial/same-origin-security-policy

Answer (score 1):

Firefox is lying to you for security. It won't return the actual value because you could use it to track users. It won't even work in the same domain in Firefox. Seems to work ok in IE9 from the same domain, otherwise it gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!-- TRY THE CODE BELOW , IT WILL WORK FINE , I DON'T KNOW WHAT'S WRONG WITH YOUR CODE !-->
    <html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function check()
{
var xwin = window.frames[0];
console.log(xwin.location);
}
</script>
<body onLoad="check()">
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com/js/"></iframe>
</body>
</html>


<!-- SORRY FOR THE MISTAKE IN EARLIER CODE  --->
```

Comment: I tried the code and the web console report the following error:
xwin not defined.
My Firefox version is 8.0. Does it matter?

Comment: Hey me also did run this code in firefox , there it worked fine , am also using the firefox version 8.0 ,  [check the screenshot](http://i43.tinypic.com/346rt4g.jpg)

Comment: To explain further, `xwin.location` will be about:blank until the iframe finishes loading, so this code waits for that to finish (by waiting for body.onload to fire) before checking the iframe location.